# Why when I create a new post I found 2 record related to this post into the posts database table?

Tags: php, posts, theme-development, database, mysql

I am very new in WordPress development and I have a doubt about the WP database table named **posts**

I have observe that when I create a new post (into the WP administration panel) are created 2 record into the **posts** table.

For example, after that I have create a single post titled as **DB TEST** into the **posts** table I found these 2 records:

```
29  1   2014-08-14 20:36:43 2014-08-14 20:36:43 deb test    DB TEST     publish open    open        db-test         2014-08-15 20:37:34 2014-08-15 20:37:34     0   http://localhost/wordpressAsper/?p=29   0   post        0

30  1   2014-08-15 20:36:43 2014-08-15 20:36:43 deb test    DB TEST     inherit open    open        29-revision-v1          2014-08-15 20:36:43 2014-08-15 20:36:43     29  http://localhost/wordpressAsper/2014/08/15/29-revi...   0   revision        0
```

As you can see the 2 records contains the same informations except for the ID (that is univocal) and for the **post_type** field. In the first record this field have **post** as value while in the secondo record the valie is **inerith**

So why when I create a new post I have 2 records and not a single record?

Moreover I noted that, for other posts, I have more the 2 records related to the same post. What exactly means?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The second one is revision. It means the changes that you made, but didn't save. Wordpress saves that as revision post. There might be more than one revision post if you make more changes without updating the post.

You don't need to worry about that. It's all in background and won't affect you in any way.

Answer (score 0):

This is many years later and using 5.2, but I just noticed this in prepping to manually migrate content from another platform. Odd that the revision is created at the same exact time as the original post, even though no revision was actually made, but comes simply at the saving of the original post. Noticed this for pages and posts both.

Interestingly, I can delete those "revision" records and no ill affects. The revision record is added back in upon edit and save.